# GraphAPI not returning user chat reactions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using `users/{id}/chats/getAllMessages` to get all user `chat` messages.

But this does not give us the `reactions` to the chat. The reaction field count is always 0.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug for the following endpoints

```
GET /users/{id}/chats/getAllMessages
GET /teams/{team-id}/channels/getAllMessages
```

Endpoints which return reactions

```
GET /users/{id}/chats/{Id}/messages
GET /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages
```

Resources
[getAllMessages doesn't return reactions](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/11670)

[Reactions not included](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/13507)